# limits and continuity !!!

Tags: calculus, limits

i am currently a highschool student and im in my junior year, anyway i have finished the Alevel maths course , currently studying the further maths course, however at the beginning of the alevel course we jumped directly to calculus without enough knowledge of limits and i feel like my mathematical knowledge has a " Gap " due to this. any ideas how can i improve my knowledge in limits ? any books , courses , anything would be appreciated . thanks,

Comment: This is generally true for high school calc courses. It takes calculus to better work with limits, and analysis to rigorously define limits, so all that is skipped in place for a simple limit definition.

Comment: so the other part of the question how can i get better in limits ? any books recommended ?

Comment: It is enough to know that a limit tells you what a function approaches, even if the function isn't defined there. For example, if you take a look at the graph of $sin(x) / x$ you'll notice that at $x = 0$, the function approaches $1$, even though its actual value at $x = 0$ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can just visit https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/limits-and-continuity-calc they provide nice video tutorials. I personally used them and find very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Stewart's Calculus book would be nice for you, I think. It has a lot of graphs and examples from which you can learn. You can download it from the internet for free.

Comment: i think i have access to  that book i will give it a try , thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Continuity

Differentiability

Convergence of a sequence

Convergence of a series

Convergence of a generalized integral

Pointwise convergence

Uniform convergence

Normal convergence

> All these notions are based on LIMITS.

So begin by the limits. the future will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to understand what a limit is in order to "do" calculus.  After all, limits were not defined until 1820's and calculus was discovered (invented) closer to 1700.  But limits put calculus on a solid theoretical foundation.

Now, some practitioners don't care so much about foundations, and they care about the implications.  So, many introductory calculus courses hand-waive their way passed this bit of theory, and jump straight into applications.  And for those who care about theory, they take their 2 years of calculus and circle back to the foundations in "Real Analysis."

This is all just a long winded way of saying you are not alone.  And if you really want to gain a strong grasp of limits, continuity, etc. you need to be looking at Real Analysis books and classes.

The "bible" of real analysis texts is "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.  aka "baby Rudin."  You can find this text on-line and download it.

That said, this text is dense, and will be difficult to follow without someone to explain to you what you are reading.  There is an on-line series of lectures on Real Analysis by Francis Su that are excellent.  Nonetheless, it will still be a difficult subject to self-study.

If you are looking for tools, tricks and gimmicks to find limits, then disregard all of the preceding.

Comment: thank you for that sophisticated answer , may i ask , if you can suggest a topic then that i can benefit from studying ? , i considered number theory/combinatorics as   i want to participate in the imo but i find them exceptionally hard. i can solve some number theory problems by intuition tho .

Comment: Linear Algebra would be my first suggestion.  It provides a good jumping off point to either go to multi-variate calculus or Abstract Algebra.

Comment: im taking the further mathematics AL and i think that linear algebra , complex numbers , calculus , hyperbolic functions , series like mclauren and taylor are included , so  i think i will get to linear algebra anyway i want something to study other than school subjects

Comment: I think both Newton and Leibniz used limits (although not in the same rigorous form as we see it now, they rather used infinitesimals). Without the Fundamental idea of limit it is simply not possible to differentiate unless you just keep a table lot derivatives of elementary functions. It is best to learn limits (even an informal definition with simple example would suffice) including various limit laws (omit proofs if unsuitable). This is typical of high school textbooks of calculus in India.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I am thinking of $\epsilon - \delta$ definitions limits.  Certainly earlier mathematicians had a concept of the infinitesimal perturbation to the input and corresponding change in the output.